# allow string only once in regex

Tags: regex

Assume I have a very long string like:

```
helloABCABC 100gABC
```

and I want to delete one of the ABC substrings so it show only the first occurrence of it.

the desired output is:

```
helloABC 100g
```

I tried with positive lookahead, but it didn't work so well.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you please show your look-ahead? And what language are you using, JavaScript?

Comment: The double `l` should also be replaced in `hello`. There's a logical failure here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
ABC(?=.*?ABC)
```

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/kY8kZ9/1) you can find a demo.

Comment: thanks a lot enrico.bacis ! any chance that we can handle a general case for that?

Answer (score 2):

You could [do this](https://www.debuggex.com/r/Y3Cjm-ZqmRJQe7xS) and then [replace with `$1`](https://regex101.com/r/rW3nP8/1):

```
(.{2,})\1+
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

But @HamZa is absolutely right that you might catch things that are perfectly valid. I made it such that the repeated string needs to have at least 2 characters (so 4 characters including its first repetition). But this doesn't eliminate the logical problem.

You can see in the above [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/rW3nP8/1) this word [hottentottententententoonstelling](http://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hottentottententententoonstelling) which is a legitimate word in Dutch (my language) being falsely vandalized by the regex replace. I'm sure you could think of scenarios like this in English or your language of choice.

Answer (score 0):

No need for regular expressions:

```
    $index = strpos($str, 'ABC');
    $result = substr($str, 0, $index + 3) . str_replace('ABC', '', substr($str, $index + 3));
```

This would also be faster than using the regular expressions engine.

Comment: @Gck Did you even try my solution? It also works with your edit.

Comment: Problem is that I should do it by regex, because after I run it in a script, so I can't actually implement anything but regex.